# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module 'TestClass' couldn't be found

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I searched multiple other questions, but their answers didn't helped or I was unable to implement them correctly. From them, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948184/sphinx-autoclass-not-importing-module) is pretty much the same like me issue I think.

The structure of my directory is the following:

```
DashboardV3
   TestClass.py

   doc
      source
         index.rst
         conf.py
```

I want to document the following class `TestClass.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

class MyClass:
    def preprocess_dataframe(path):
        df = pd.read_csv(path)

        return df
```

I have included the following path setup within `conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('./'))
print(sys.path)
```

`Index.rst` definition is the following:

```
Welcome!
=========================================

.. automodule:: testClass.MyClass
    :members:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
```

However, I am receiving the following error when running `make html`:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`

Which is part of the total print log:

```
Running Sphinx v1.8.5
loading translations [de]... done
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [] 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'TestClass'; the following exception was raised:
DLL load failed: The specified module not be found
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
generating indices... genindex py-modindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in German (code: de) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in build\html.
```

Just to be clear: I tried to implement several solutions from all the other questions ask beforehand and I'm asking because I propably failed to incorporate the correct answers.

I am coding within VS Code, if this is from interest.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It may be helpful to reduce this to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I reduced the example

Comment: You now have a syntax error. Read the entire page I linked again. Your example should work in every way except the error you'd like help with, and should be as simple as possible. Also, show the entire stack trace you're getting. Not just the last line.

Comment: @JonMcClung The error is the given error from ```make html``` in cmd. There is nothing more than this. I added code functionality to the function definition.

Comment: What happens if you remove `import numpy as np` and `from numba import jit`? These imports are not used in your class.

Comment: It's stil the same problem

Comment: OK. What happens if you remove `import pandas as pd` and don't use pandas at all in your class?

Comment: @mzjn No change at all if I remove the import statements everywhere

Comment: My comments were just shots in the dark. I suspect it will be hard to help if you cannot provide an actual [mcve].

Comment: How should I reduced this example further? What information do I need to provide additionally?